# thinking sphinx issue on ec2 production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2, thinking-sphinx

I am using sphinx to search on models I am using delta indexing. Things work fine on my local development machine(Ubuntu). However on ec2 production env, when I create new records, I need to build the index again in order to make the newly created records search-able.

I have checked for permissions, thinking sphinx gem version and they all seem to be fine. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I suggest having a look into this https://github.com/agibralter/ts-resque-delta
Delta indexing can have inconsistencies, I am using the above solution is great for delta indexing. But a cron job run every once in a while to completely re-index thinking sphinx is a good way to insure your indexed data matches your database data.